# generating a lookup using Entity Framork 5 inappropriately repeats query per row

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Learning EF5. I have a UserRole table that stores user role relationships, with a UserID column which FKs to a User table, and a RoleID column that FKs to a Role table.

Edmx generation from the database refuses to generate this UserRole table into the designer, since it gives me "navigation" properties in the User and Role tables to get this relationship information... which is fine.

But the first query I try to generate a lookup for an authentication cache (`cx` is the DbContext)

```
var userRoles = cx.Users.ToLookup(
    o => o.UserID, 
    o => o.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleID));
```

causes EF to execute a query for every user.

I really would have preferred just having access to the UserRole table directly to generate the lookup. But, barring that, how should I write this code to get a better projection - i.e., have the data returned with only one SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the answer instead of deleting it in case it can help someone else. Or maybe someone will post an improvement or correction.

This expression causes EF to retrieve the data using a single SQL statement.

```
var userRoles = cx.Users.SelectMany(u => 
    u.Roles.Select(r => 
        new { userID = u.UserID, roleID = r.RoleID })).
    ToLookup(o => o.userID, o => o.roleID);
```

You have to use an anonymous type and not `KeyValuePair<string, string>` here, because LINQ projection won't understand that.

And for reference, how to push EF's SQL into your unit tests' output to eyeball it -

```
public YourDatabaseNameEntities()
    : base("name=YourDatabaseEntities")
{
#if TRACE
    this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(s);
#endif
}
```

which can be persistantly included in your generated code via the associated .tt file.